# Doubt based on program in SCJP(EXAM 310-065)

Tags: java, constructor, scjp

```
class Top{
public Top(String s){System.out.print("B");}
}

public class Bottom2 extends Top{
    public Bottom2(String s){System.out.print("D");}
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Bottom2("C");
        System.out.println(" ");
} }
```

In the above program, I guessed the output must be `BD`, but in the book they said the compilation fails. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: And did you try to compile the program yourself to see?

Answer (score 3):

The derived class `Bottom2` is required to call the base class constructor using `super`, otherwise you'll get a compile error. For example, if you do this, it will compile:

```
public Bottom2(String s) { super(s); System.out.print("D"); }
```

See [the section on Subclass Constructors](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).

Answer (score 2):

When you have public Top(String s) then java doesn't create the default constructor with no arguments then when you write the child class, the constructor look for the default constructor (because you are not calling explictly)... then the compilations fails.